# Space Filling curve in hypercube

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a space filling curve $\gamma:[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ how can I define a space filling curve from $\gamma:[0,1] \to [0,1]^3$ for example? My initial thought was to just use the map (id, $\gamma$) but I don't think this works.

Thanks

Comment: Given space-filling curves $a:[0,1]\to A$ and $b:[0,1]\to B,$ use $\gamma$ to find a space-filling curve $[0,1]\to A\times B.$

Comment: So since a map to the product is uniquely determined by maps to the projections, the maps id and $\gamma$ work then?

Comment: For $[0,1]^3,$ yes, and for $[0,1]^n,$ by induction.

Comment: If you write $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\gamma_2),$ you can write the map explicitly for $n=3.$ $$t\mapsto (\gamma_1(\gamma_1(t)),\gamma_2(\gamma_1(t)),\gamma_2(t))$$

Comment: My confusion then lies in the fact that by the same logic (id,id) is a space filling curve to $[0,1]^2$ which seems odd.

Comment: It's not, because $\gamma$ needs to be involved. I didn't say $(a,b)$ is the space-filling curve.

Comment: I had written down your explicit map before but confused myself since t = 0 does not map to (0,0,0) if $\gamma(0) \neq 0)$ so how can it be subjective?

Comment: Nothing requires $f(0)=(0,0,0).$ Some other element can go there.

Comment: If $\gamma_1(a)=0=\gamma_2(a)$ then then there is some $t$ such that $\gamma(t)=(a,0).$ Then $$(\gamma_1(\gamma_1(t))=\gamma_1(a)=0,\\\gamma_2(\gamma_1(a))=\gamma_2(a)=0,\\\gamma_2(t)=0.$$ So my function is onto $(0,0,0).$ You can do this more generally.